# What does [::] mean in my nginx config file

Tags: nginx

I was looking at my nginx config file I noticed two this.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html;
}
```

I understand this part `listen 80 default_server;` it tells nginx to listen on port 80 and set that as the "default_server" but I do not understand the second line.

`listen [::]:80 default_server;`

It appears I am setting the default server again on port 80 but I do not really understand the `[::]` part of it at all.

Can someone explain to me what this configuration does?

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is for the IPv6 configs

from the nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

```
IPv6 addresses (0.7.36) are specified in square brackets:

listen [::]:8000;
listen [::1];
```